# Fix the gaps in the left and right side of content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and trying to tweak one of the free template for admin needs. Right now the content inside `#page-wrapper` leaves too much space on either side when the window is maximized. I tried playing with different padding, margin size but then the responsiveness loses and the horizontal scroll bar appears. How can I reduce the spaces on both the left and right side of this content without losing responsiveness.

Please find the screen shot below[image]

The fiddle is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/suyesh/F5WP3/)

The template was working fine originally but when I wrap it inside the `bootstrap container div`, I get this problem.

Comment: hello mate, 
are you mean, this problem happend when you press ( ctrl & + ) only ?, Since i would ask this problem display on big screen too...

Comment: No I am not saying about  ctrl & + (zoom), this problem happens in big screen. For the reduced screen size the gaps are adjusting nicely.

Comment: are you try to use media query & js validate window when resize, I have idea, its by set media query such as min-width: 2000px; this by script will be cheked is screen size more than 2000 this one, then by script calculate a margin-left, margin-right to know what is size, now as normal gab must be 20px and you find it 30, thats mean by script change margin to 20 and then increase 10 to div wrapper..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the container to container-fluid

Comment: Simple as that. Just starting out with bootstrap so did not realize. That solved the problem but I see my forms getting a bit wider but that is not an issue, cheers mate.

Comment: Yes using fluid will literally stick the container to the parent container. Good for smart tvs!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.container` class as wrapper. It has specific width adjustment, which depends upon screen resolution. You should use `.container-fluid` class for a fluid layout. Or otherwise you have to edit bootstrap css file. See the css code:

```
.container{margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px}
@media (min-width:768px){.container{width:750px}}
@media (min-width:992px){.container{width:970px}}
@media (min-width:1200px){.container{width:1170px}}
.container-fluid{margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px}
```

Comment: Had to accept the other answer which I got earlier. Upvote for you. Thanks.